# Check Python builtin libraries files in Android Studio using chaquopy

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, chaquopy

I am using `pytube` using `chaquopy` in `android studio` and getting error `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.chaquo.python.PyException: RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W`

I know that I have to replace the code in `cipher.py`

```
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")
```

With that line:

```
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\$*\w+\W")
```

I could able to locate `cipher.py` in `C:\Users\....\AndroidStudioProjects\YouTubeDownloader\app\build\pip\debug\common\pytube\cipher.py` directory and changed the above expression with the new code. But still on execution of the above code, It is showing the same error, and  Upon revisiting the cipher.py file, I notice that the code has reverted back to the original version.

I'm uncertain whether I'm performing the modification incorrectly or if I'm unable to locate the correct `cipher.py` file, Where the Android Studio keep the python module files in it. Could someone please provide guidance on how to effectively make these changes to the `cipher.py` file from within Android Studio? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

- Download the pytube source distribution from https://pypi.org/project/pytube/#files
- Unpack it
- Apply your edits
- Edit your build.gradle file so that instead of this:

  ```
  install "pytube"
  ```

  You have this:

  ```
  install "path/to/your/edited/pytube"
  ```

Comment: Hey !! Thanks.. I was struggling with it since morning.. Its done perfectly ..